# How can I set the JOOQ generator up to not prefix types with package names

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have generated classes from my database Schema with JOOQ. All types are prefixed with their package names in the generated classes (e.g. org.jooq.TableField). This makes the generated code barely readable. Can I parametrize the generator such that it only imports the pacakges and then specifies the types without the packages (e.g. TableField) ?

Here is my configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.3.0.xsd">
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
    <user>root</user>
    <password></password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>

    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
      <inputSchema>mydb</inputSchema>
      <includes>.*</includes>

      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>

    <target>
      <packageName>my.package.for.generated.classes</packageName>

      <directory>/home/nicolas/dev/Java/my.project/src/main/java/</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't support generating `import` statements because of all the possible naming clashes with existing types. In other words, it's not possible to prevent that with jOOQ 3.3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any plan to implement such functionality ? I'm sure those potential clashes may be avoided either by detecting conflicts or by configuration.

Comment: @NicolasSeiller: There is [#2884](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2884) for this, but right now, we're not in a hurry to implement it. While it obviously does improve readability, it is far from trivial to get it right for edge cases (we have customers naming their database tables or procedures `STRING` and `INTEGER`...). I guess, though, that we could be implementing a flag that would allow for switching this on and off, postponing the harder name mangling for later... I'll register this as [#3336](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3336)